# Terrform Module for Azure APIM Definitions

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I´m using Terraform to deploy Azure Api management. So far Was able to create the service, api, policies  and operations but there is not a module in where I can find definitions in json format for the operations and how I can associate an operation with a definition.

This are all the components that I found: [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation)

Is there a way of include them with terraform somehow?

[image]

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  
}

data "azurerm_api_management" "apim_service" {
  name                = "${var.apim_service}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.66.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
 provider "azurerm" {
   features {}
 }


resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sample-api" {
  name                = "Test-2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "API-1"
  path                = "API"
  protocols           = ["https", "http"]
  description         = "example"
  
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "get-info" {
  operation_id        = "info"
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  display_name        = "Get info Testing"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/info"
  description         = "foo"

  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
  response {
    status_code = 400
  }
  response {
    status_code = 401
  }
  response {
    status_code = 403
  }
  response {
    status_code = 404
  }

}


resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "sample-api" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  #operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.sample-api.operation_id

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="/api/info" copy-params="true" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://foo-dev.azurewebsites.net" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
XML
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide terraform code that you have used ,so that we can refer it and provide the solution based on that.

Comment: Just updated the code, but don´t know if what is needed. Need to know what is the module or how I can add "Definitions" using APIM

Comment: Isee in this post how the definitions structure is made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961623/api-management-api-schema-definition-create-multiple-definitions-under-1-schem but can´t find a place of how to add it using terraform

Comment: Also with ARM templates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620293/how-to-include-openapi-schema-definitions-into-an-arm-template/69255405#69255405

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this on my environment using your code by doing some changes.
If you want to add the definition to the operation, then you can do it by using something like below:

**CODE:**

```html
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
      name = "Your resource group name"
      
    }


    data "azurerm_api_management" "apim_service" {
      name                = "your apim service name"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      
    }


    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "=2.66.0"
        }
      }
    }


    # Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider

     provider "azurerm" {
       features {}
     }

  
  resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sample-api" {
      name                = "Test-2"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
      revision            = "1"
      display_name        = "API-1"
      path                = "API"
      protocols           = ["https", "http"]
      description         = "example"
      
    }


    resource "azurerm_api_management_api_schema" "example" {
      api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.name
      api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.api_management_name
      resource_group_name = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.resource_group_name
      schema_id           = "example-schema"
      content_type        = "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json"
      value               = <<JSON
      {
    "properties": {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
        "document": {
          "components": {
            "schemas": {
                "Definition1": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "String1": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Definition2": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "String2": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    JSON
    }


    resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "get-info" {
      operation_id        = "info"
      api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.name
      api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      display_name        = "Get info Testing"
      method              = "POST"
      url_template        = "/info"
      description         = "foo"
      request {
         representation {
        schema_id    = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.schema_id
        content_type = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.content_type
        sample = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.value
        type_name = "test"
      }
      }
      response {
        status_code = 200
      }
      response {
        status_code = 400
      }
      response {
        status_code = 401
      }
      response {
        status_code = 403
      }
      response {
        status_code = 404
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

> **NOTE:** This is just an example .You can provide your own definition in
> the  `resource "azurerm_api_management_api_schema" "example"`  **value**.

As for the solution we have created api schema and then used it in operation by adding the below:

```
request {
     representation {
    schema_id    = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.schema_id
    content_type = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.content_type
    sample = azurerm_api_management_api_schema.example.value
    type_name = "test"
  }
  }
```

for which the definition has been created .

Comment: it worked! thank you

Comment: hello @kavyasaraboju-MT is there a way to create on same API different operations? with the aproach of Schemas? who would yo do it?

Comment: No. That one does not work. The "definition" is not created and the openapi document is broken