# Azure APIM - deploying a schema via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I'm looking to deploy a schema via terraform to Azure APIM.
Here is the TF Code based on [TF Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_schema) and other examples on SO, such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229878/terrform-module-for-azure-apim-definitions):

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_schema" "api_schema" {
  api_name            = var.api.name
  api_management_name = var.apim_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  schema_id           = "schema01"
  content_type        = "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json"
  value               = file("schema.json")
}
```

And here is the contents of the **schema.json** file

```
{
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
    "document": {
      "components": {
        "schemas": {
          "Thing": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          },
          "ThingArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Thing"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the Terraform, there are no errors. However, there are also no definitions visible in the portal:
[image: Azure APIM Portal - No definitions]

If I use Azure API to get the schema, I get the following response - which seems to have the value as a string rather than pure JSON:

```
{
    "id": "***REDACTED***",
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
    "name": "schema01",
    "properties": {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
        "document": {
            "value": "{\r\n  \"properties\": {\r\n    \"contentType\": \"application\/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json\",\r\n    \"document\": {\r\n      \"components\": {\r\n        \"schemas\": {\r\n          \"Thing\": {\r\n            \"type\": \"object\",\r\n            \"properties\": {\r\n              \"id\": {\r\n                \"type\": \"string\",\r\n                \"nullable\": true\r\n              }\r\n            },\r\n            \"additionalProperties\": false\r\n          },\r\n          \"ThingArray\": {\r\n            \"type\": \"array\",\r\n            \"items\": {\r\n              \"$ref\": \"#\/components\/schemas\/Thing\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
        }
    }
}
```

If I use the API to update the schema via the PUT method, using the same **schema.json** as the payload, the value looks correct (all pure JSON):

```
{
    "id": "***REDACTED***",
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
    "name": "schema01",
    "properties": {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
        "document": {
            "components": {
                "schemas": {
                    "Thing": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "nullable": true
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    },
                    "ThingArray": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Thing"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and the definitions appear in the portal:

[image: Azure APIM Portal - Has definitions]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***I ran the below terraform script and the Definitions were not visible in the Azure Portal in Azure APIM resource.***

```
terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm =  {

source = "hashicorp/azurerm"

version = "3.8.0"

}

}

}

  

provider  "azurerm" {

subscription_id =  "<subscription-id>"

tenant_id =  "<tenant-id>"

client_id =  "<client-id>"

client_secret =  "<client-secret>"

features {}

}

  

data  "azurerm_resource_group"  "rg" {

name =  "siliconrg098"

}

  
  

data  "azurerm_api_management"  "apim_service" {

name =  "siliconapim"

resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

}

  
  

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider

# provider "azurerm" {

# features {}

# }

  

resource  "azurerm_api_management_api"  "sample-api" {

name =  "Test-2"

resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name

revision =  "1"

display_name =  "API-1"

path =  "API"

protocols =  ["https", "http"]

description =  "example"

}

  
  

resource  "azurerm_api_management_api_schema"  "example" {

api_name =  azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.name

api_management_name =  azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.api_management_name

resource_group_name =  azurerm_api_management_api.sample-api.resource_group_name

schema_id =  "example-schema"

content_type =  "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json"

value =  <<JSON

{

{

"properties": {

"contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",

"document": {

"components": {

"schemas": {

"Thing": {

"type": "object",

"properties": {

"id": {

"type": "string",

"nullable": true

}

},

"additionalProperties": false

},

"ThingArray": {

"type": "array",

"items": {

"$ref": "#/components/schemas/Thing"

}

}

}

}

}

}

}

JSON

}
```

**Output:-**

I **did not see** any **definition in the APIM resource** like below:-

[image]

Also, When I **checked the API schema in my Azure APIM resource, It was similar to what you got in the API call**, refer below:-

[image]

***Inorder to Create a definition I used proper Open API schema with the terraform code below:-***

```
terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm  =  {

source = "hashicorp/azurerm"

version = "=3.0.0"

}

}

}

  

provider  "azurerm" {

subscription_id  =  "<subscription-id>"

tenant_id  =  "<tenant-id>"

client_id  =  "<client-id>"

client_secret  =  "<client-secret>"

features {}

}

  

data  "azurerm_resource_group"  "rg" {

name  =  "siliconrg098"

}

  

data  "azurerm_api_management"  "apim_service" {

name  =  "siliconapim"

resource_group_name  =  data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

}

  

resource  "azurerm_api_management_api"  "example" {

name  =  "example-api"

resource_group_name  =  data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

api_management_name  =  data.azurerm_api_management.apim_service.name

display_name  =  "Example API"

path  =  "example"

protocols  =  ["https"]

revision  =  "1"

  

import {

content_format  =  "swagger-json"

content_value  =  <<EOF

{

"swagger": "2.0",

"info": {

"version": "1.0.0",

"title": "Example API"

},

"paths": {},

"definitions": {

"Thing": {

"type": "object",

"properties": {

"id": {

"type": "string"

}

}

},

"ThingArray": {

"type": "array",

"items": {

"$ref": "#/definitions/Thing"

}

}

}

}

EOF

}

}
```

***And the APIM Definition Thing and Thing array got created successfully like below:-***

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated resource in Terraform - `azurerm_api_management_global_schema` - that is responsible for schema management per API Management service

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_schema

So your terraform script can be:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_global_schema" "snowflake_schema" {
  schema_id           = "snowflake_schema"
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  type                = "json"
  value               = file("api_management_api_snowflake_schema.json")
}
```

After execution `snowflake_schema` will be created inside Schemas of APIM service

[image]